# Determine transport method in SignalR Core?

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

In SignalR 2.0 the transport method can be determined by the `transport` parameter in the query string.

```
string transportMethod = queryString["transport"];
```

This doesn't seem to be the case in SignalR for ASP.NET Core.

The best I can do, it seems, is to use header information.

For **WebSocket** connections:

```
Connection = Upgrade
Upgrade = Websocket
```

And **long polling**:

```
Connection = Keep-Alive
```

And **server-sent events**:

```
Connection = Keep-Alive
Accept = text/event-stream
```

Is there a better/easier way to go about determining the transport method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the transport type from the HubCallerContext like so

```
 Context.Items[ConnectionMetadataNames.Transport]
```

Comment: `Items` doesn't exist on `HubCallerContext`, but I did find it at `Context.Connection.Metadata[ConnectionMetadataNames.Transport]` - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To get Signalr TransportType.

```
Context.Features.Get<IHttpTransportFeature>().TransportType.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53577064/2068719

```
// using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Features;

var transportType = Context.Features.Get<IHttpTransportFeature>().TransportType;
```