# How to get the AspNet Core SignalR Transport Protocol in the Hub?

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

In the old SignalR, you could do this to get the transport in the Hub on the Server:

```
Context.QueryString["transport"];
```

But in the new SignalR, written for AspNet Core, I couldn't find where the Transport Protocol can be found within the Hub on the Server. Can it be found? If so, where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of ASP.NET Core SignalR `1.0.0-rc1-final` ([commit](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/commit/8b1a7e9199583e181bb0cbdb38481f6259dbd0c1)), you can get the `TransportType` from:

```cs
// using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Features;

var transportType = Context.Features.Get<IHttpTransportFeature>().TransportType;
```