# How to determine which transport method/protocol Azure SignalR is using?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I want to know how to get the Transfer Method/Protocol for ASP.NET Core SignalR when you are using the Azure backend.

The typical method for ASP.NET Core SignalR does not work; the "Get" call below is null. No other features have the transport type. And there were no Items.

```cs
// using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Features;

var transportType = Context.Features.Get<IHttpTransportFeature>().TransportType;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53577064/2068719

Comment: I think the final negotiation winds up in tcp header.

Comment: @JohnPeters Do you know how we can get to it?

Comment: You can use wireshark to actually see the negotiation